# Using Gateway + VirtualService + http01 + SDS

Tags: kubernetes, istio

In the [document](https://istio.io/docs/examples/advanced-gateways/ingress-certmgr/) there is an example about **Securing Kubernetes Ingress with Cert-Manager** which is not using Gateway + VirtualService.

I have tried to make it work with acme http01 but the certificate can not be issued as in log challenge I have 404 error. Seems it can not access to domain checking challenges. Is there any best practice with the specifications that I mentioned?

[Update 1]

I want to use [istio gateway](https://istio.io/blog/2019/custom-ingress-gateway/) with `SDS` option for `TLS` and secure that by using [cert-manager with http-01](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/tasks/issuers/setup-acme/http01/index.html#).

According to the documentation I found some example like [Securing Kubernetes Ingress with Cert-Manager](https://istio.io/docs/examples/advanced-gateways/ingress-certmgr/) or [Deploy a Custom Ingress Gateway Using Cert-Manager](https://istio.io/blog/2019/custom-ingress-gateway/). However these examples are using Kuberenetes Ingress resource itself (Not istio gateway) or like the second example is using `dns-01`.

I need an instruction which including [istio gateway](https://istio.io/blog/2019/custom-ingress-gateway/) with `SDS` option for `TLS` and secure that by using [cert-manager with http-01](https://docs.cert-manager.io/en/latest/tasks/issuers/setup-acme/http01/index.html#). Istio gateway give me ability to use `VirtualService`.

Thanks!

Comment: try to put much more information about your question in order to achieve your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer but not really sure why this way. I have followed [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/examples/advanced-gateways/ingress-certmgr/) with some changes.

First I edited the `istio-autogenerated-k8s-ingress` using `kubectl -n istio-system edit gateway` command. 
I removed whole the `HTTPS` part and I left `HTTP` part there.

Then I created another `Gateway` something like :

```sh
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - 'example.com'
    port:
      name: http
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP2
    tls:
      httpsRedirect: true
  - hosts:
    - 'example.com'
    port:
      name: https-default
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      credentialName: ingress-cert-staging
      mode: SIMPLE
      privateKey: sds
      serverCertificate: sds
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: bookinfo
spec:
  hosts:
  - "example.com"
  gateways:
  - bookinfo-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /productpage
    - uri:
        exact: /login
    - uri:
        exact: /logout
    - uri:
        prefix: /api/v1/products
    route:
    - destination:
        host: productpage
        port:
          number: 9080

EOF
```

With this cert-manager issued my certificate ( I guess by `istio-autogenerated-k8s-ingress` Gateway!! no idea!!) and I can create multiple Gateway and Virtual Service like example above. So everything work well!! This is just my idea and doing blindly is not a right way. Please if you have better answer and you know why the stuff happening like the way I explained let me know.

Thanks!